# Jenkinsfile Groovy closures: Default values for arguments coming up as null

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, closures, jenkins-groovy

I created a wrapper closure around the [`sh`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) Jenkins task step to allow me to capture stderr and to capture and print it to the log.

My issue is that the default values for the Boolean arguments are always coming up as `null`, unless I explicitly pass in a `true` or `false`.

Here is an example of how I call it (note that `pytest` is a closure that just builds a command to run pytest and returns a String):

```
def sh_stdout = sh_wrap(pytest("some args to a closure called pytest", "more args"))
```

Here is the snippet of the wrapper for `sh`:

```
sh_wrap = { String cmd, Boolean print_to_log = true, Boolean capture_stdout = true, Boolean capture_stderr = false ->
    echo "cmd ${cmd}"
    echo "print_to_log ${print_to_log}"
    echo "capture_stdout ${capture_stdout}"
    echo "capture_stderr ${capture_stderr}"
    if(capture_stderr) {
        cmd += ' 2>&1'
    }
    sh_stdout = sh(script: cmd, returnStdout: capture_stdout)
    if(print_to_log) {
        echo sh_stdout
    }
    return sh_stdout
}
```

Comment: You would probably benefit here from Jenkins shared library global var methods. It would fix your issue as it allows default value specification in input parameters.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thank you for the reply. Is the issue due to scope of the argument variables? Would you happen to have some examples or a toturial link? I'm very new to Groovy, but have experience in Java and Python.

Comment: Doc has more information about defining methods with default parameter values: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables

Comment: @MattSchuchard I see. Thank you for that. I wonder why the caveat of default values only working in the shared library isn't mentioned when default values were covered in this section of the docs: http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_normal_parameters